# Discord py command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to get the values ​​of two variables in a command function. In the example, I want to use a variable to define par.count(par2)

```
@commands.command()
    async def count(self, ctx, par, par2):
        x = par.count(par2)
        emBed = discord.Embed(title="try count", description="", color=0x6F9DC3)
        emBed.add_field(name="Output", value='text = "{0}"\nx = text.count({1})\nprint(x)' .format(par, par2))
        emBed.add_field(name="Result", value='{0}' .format(x))
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=emBed)
```

This is my result on discord embed when I input in discord "count i love you so much love" it defines the letter i as the text variable and love as the count variable, Any ideas to make the user input two variables to make my commands work?

```
Output                   Result
text = "i"               0
x = text.count(love)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*` before the variable that will catch the rest of the command context.

```py
@commands.command()
async def count(self, ctx, word, *, text):
    x = text.count(word)
...
```

**Example usage:**

`count love I love you so much, love` 
(<*command*> <*word you want to count*> <*text*>)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am not completely sure what u want but as I understand it the following could help:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, *args):
    await ctx.send('{} arguments: {}'.format(len(args), ', '.join(args)))
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#variable

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).